# How to access putty using Django

Tags: django

I am new to Django and i was wondering if i can do some backend testing using Django. I have already installed Django in windows. My work usually deals with putty(e.g. opening files, checking some data in a file, but this all is done in a putty box). So i was hoping if somehow i can take all the work from backend to front end by accessing putty from django(e.g creating a link to start a putty session, logging in and performing some operations). Please help me in providing the information if this can be done and if its possible, how to do it.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Django's front end is HTTP-based, not CLI based.

Answer (score 4):

For a start, you need to learn the difference between *putty* (a Windows application that emulates a remote terminal) and `ssh`, a protocol for logging into remote systems. So, if you want to do something remotely via Python, you should be thinking about how to start an SSH session, rather than how to automate putty particularly. You might, for example, look into the [paramiko](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/) library, which does just that.

Secondly, as the other answerers have mentioned, this seems an odd requirement. Web frameworks are not ideally suited to doing things like this. If you just want to automate some remote operations, perhaps [fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.2.0/index.html) is what you need.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I made use of paramiko and was able to login into the remote terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Since putty is a different application you need to spawn a subprocess and communicate with the application through stdin and stdout. This can be done using the [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) module.

But please remenber, that Django is a web framework. This means it is for creating web application. Your problem looks more like a general "I want to automate something" problem where you don't need a web framework - you can simply use pure python. Is there any reason why you are using Django?

Comment: Thanks for your quick response on my querry :). Generally i want to make some front end tools that performs the operations in putty, for e.g. i open a web page and provide the remote terminal name, username and password for that terminal and then provide a list of commands. Now if i click on a button(say "start"), this will start a session and perorm the operations in putty as given by the user and then return back the final response or response at the end of every single command as httpresponse and displays in the web page.

Comment: I have already automated lot of stuff using pure python in putty but that keeps me to a more of black box stuff. I was wondering if i can perfrom all my operation from a web page instead of logging into remote terminal and then doing the stuff there plus i am very keen to learn Django(since i already know python). So this serves both the purposes.:)